# Mangento - How to show Shipping fee in Subtotal but not calculated in Grand Total?

Tags: php, magento

I am currently using Mangeto 1.9.1 and a custom shipping method which is the only one for my store.

Everything works cool but i want the shipping price to appear in the subtotal when order is created but to be not calculated in the Grand Total?

How i can show the shipping fee in subtotal but this fee must not be calculated and added in Grand Total ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I bet you could probably subtract it using math you learned in grade school if you really wanted to.

Comment: You get a code editor, then find the appropriate code, then remove the function that adds the shipping fee or simply always return 0 and only display it as text through another function.

Comment: This is not what i wanted...